# getting gmail message as batch request from gmail api

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

messageList we are sending message ids

```
function getGmailMessagesBatch(oauth2Client, messagesList){
var batchBody = \[\];
var indReq = '';
if(oauth2Client && oauth2Client.credentials && oauth2Client.credentials.access_token){
/*Generating the request body for the batch request
according to gmail api docs for batching multiple api calls into one request
each request should a part of the request body, so doing that below
refer to gmail api docs for details info*/
\_.each(messagesList,function(eachMessage){
indReq='';
indReq = "--request_boundary\\n"+
"Authoriz
ation: Bearer "+oauth2Client.credentials.access_token+"\\n"+
"Content-Type: application/http\\n\\n"+
"GET /gmail/v1/users/"+data.userEmail+"/messages/"+eachMessage.id+"\\n";
batchBody.push(indReq);
})
batchBody.push("--request_boundary--\\n");
batchBody = batchBody.join('\\n');
//Sending the batch request
rp({
uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1',
method: 'POST',
headers: {
"content-type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=request_boundary"
},
body:batchBody,
resolveWithFullResponse: true
})
.then(function(response){
/*The response is stringified & the response to each of the api calls present
in the batch request is seperated by a boundary which is present in the content
type header of the response,therefore we need to parse the response to
obtain the actual data*/
var parsedResponse = parseBatchResponse(response);
return cb(null, parsedResponse);
})
.catch(function(error){
sails.log.error('Error in getting messages async in eachseries',error,data);
return cb('Unexpected error!');
})
}else{
sails.log.error('Access token missing to sync emails using gmail api',data);
return cb('Authorization failure!');
}
}
```

in the parsedResponse the error i am getting is

{"error":{"code":401,"message":"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.","errors":[{"message":"Login](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22,%22errors%22:%5B%7B%22message%22:%22Login) Required.","domain":"global","reason":"required","location":"Authorization","locationType":"header"}],"status":"UNAUTHENTICATED","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo","reason":"CREDENTIALS_MISSING","domain":"googleapis.com","metadata":{"service":"gmail.googleapis.com","method":"caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.GetMessage"}}]}}

i am expecting to get messages from gmail of specific ids

trying to get gmail messages from gmail api

Comment: Is that your full code? Based on the error, it means that the method you are calling is missing authorization and your calls are not authenticated. Have you read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes)?

Answer (score 0):

Does cleaning up the format a bit make a difference?

```java
function getGmailMessagesBatch(oauth2Client, messagesList)
{
    var batchBody = \[\];
    var indReq = '';
    if(oauth2Client && oauth2Client.credentials && oauth2Client.credentials.access_token)
    {
        /*Generating the request body for the batch request
        according to gmail api docs for batching multiple api calls into one request
        each request should a part of the request body, so doing that below
        refer to gmail api docs for details info*/
        \_.each(messagesList,function(eachMessage)
        {
            indReq='';
            indReq = "--request_boundary\\n"+
            "Authorization: Bearer "+oauth2Client.credentials.access_token+"\\n"+
            "Content-Type: application/http\\n\\n"+
            "GET /gmail/v1/users/"+data.userEmail+"/messages/"+eachMessage.id+"\\n";
            batchBody.push(indReq);
        })
        batchBody.push("--request_boundary--\\n");
        batchBody = batchBody.join('\\n');
        //Sending the batch request
        rp(
        {
            uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            "content-type": "multipart/mixed; boundary=request_boundary"
            },
            body:batchBody,
            resolveWithFullResponse: true
        })
        .then(function(response)
        {
            /*The response is stringified & the response to each of the api calls present
            in the batch request is seperated by a boundary which is present in the content
            type header of the response,therefore we need to parse the response to
            obtain the actual data*/
            var parsedResponse = parseBatchResponse(response);
            return cb(null, parsedResponse);
        })
        .catch(function(error)
        {
            sails.log.error('Error in getting messages async in eachseries',error,data);
            return cb('Unexpected error!');
        })
    } else {
        sails.log.error('Access token missing to sync emails using gmail api',data);
        return cb('Authorization failure!');
    }
}
```

I noticed the Authorization line in your original code was broken by a line break.